# Bigcommerce Api - add sku to the base product without options

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am using api to add products and i would like to add SKU to the products which is not possible. Is there any workaround for it.

As per  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/skus#create-a-product-sku the options is mandatory. But the products i created doesn't have options.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand on the sample product you are using? If there are not options, then it sounds like it is a simple product. There is a SKU field at the product level that doesn't have to be at the a variant level.

Answer (score 0):

In BigCommerce, product SKUs are referring to two things:

1. A variation of a product, which can contain options like size, color, etc.
2. SKU in the simple sense (an identifier).

For an example of (1), let's say you're selling a shoe that's size 10 (SKU: SHOE10), size 11 (SHOE11), and size 12 (SHOE12). The shoe is the *product*, the specific sizes you're buying are the *SKUs*. So these SKUs can have options like size, color, etc. SKU: SHOE10 has a size of 10.

If you have no options for your product, it sounds like you're not selling a variation, you're selling a single product. You want option (2). In this case, you want to use the [products endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#create-a-product), not the SKU endpoint as you linked. You can add the sku that way. [Here is what the product object looks like](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/product) -- as you can see, you can pass in a value for "sku" when you create or update a product.